# Read docx file from mysql database in java

Tags: java, apache, file, docx

I have a program that stores a docx file to my MYSQL database MEDIUMBLOB data type.

How can I retrieve that file from the database and then read it using APACHE POI in order to check the number of words, paragraphs and etc? (Initial Question)

Here is my code in saving the file.

```
public void saveFile(String FileDirectory, String FileName)
{
    try {
        //Connecting to MYSQL Database
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

         //saving the image
        PreparedStatement psmnt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO doccompfiles VALUES(?,?,?)");
        psmnt.setInt(1, 5);
        psmnt.setNString(2, FileName);
        File f = new File(FileDirectory + FileName);
        psmnt.setBlob(3, new FileInputStream(f), f.length());
        psmnt.executeUpdate();

        con.close();
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error saving file");
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

Researched and found a way on how to do it, but I'm having errors at my stacktrace. Here is the code for retrieving.

```
public void loadFile(String FileName)
{
    try
    {
        //Connecting to MYSQL Database
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM doccompfiles WHERE FileName = '"+ FileName +"'");
        InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("File");

        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(is);
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of Paragraphs" + paragraphs.length);
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBinaryStream(ResultSetImpl.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBinaryStream(ResultSetImpl.java:1586)
    at documentComparisor.Database.loadFile(Database.java:150)
    at documentComparisor.Home$5.actionPerformed(Home.java:195)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can verify that the file is stored in the database and my table details in the select statement is correct. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be forgetting about `if(rs.next())` condition before retrieving the stream from the query. In your current case, your `rs.getBinaryStream()` might return `null` if query would return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

1. select your BLOB from table
   (look for getBinaryStream while processing large files, otherwise getBlob)
2. process it:

   ```
   HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(binaryStream);
   WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

   String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
   System.out.println("Total Paragraphs: "+paragraphs.length);

   (then iterate through paragraphs array and count words)
   ```

Comment: Can you please state an example regarding retrieving the BLOB from the "select" statement and insert it to the stream? Thanks

Comment: Made something up for retrieving the file. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for read and write blob data from database

```java
public class ReadBlobData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeBlob(65, "Test.docx");
        readBlob(65, "Test.docx");

    }

    public static void readBlob(int candidateId, String filename) {

        String selectSQL = "SELECT  document_text FROM scope1.documents where id=?";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try (Connection conn = MySQLJDBCUtil.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);) {
            // set parameter;
            pstmt.setInt(1, candidateId);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            // write binary stream into file
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Writing to file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            while (rs.next()) {
                InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("document_text");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void writeBlob(int candidateId, String filename) {
        // update sql
        String updateSQL = "UPDATE scope1.documents " + 
                " SET  document_text=? WHERE id=?";

        try (Connection conn = MySQLJDBCUtil.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL)) {

            // read the file
            File file = new File("/home/hardik/Desktop/Test.docx");
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            System.out.println(file.length());

            // set parameters
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, input);
            pstmt.setInt(2, candidateId);

            // store the resume file in database
            System.out.println("Reading file " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Store file in the database.");

        } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}



public class MySQLJDBCUtil {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;

            // assign db parameters
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scope1" ;
            String user ="root" ;
            String password = "root";

            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        return conn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if your code is a solution to poster's problem, it is more helpful with explanations and comments, especially on points of interest and parts where the poster choked may have special highlight. Also you did not format the code block. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting